# CoreData:how to display image in UIImageView in CoreData

Tags: ios

i am working on CoreData.i saved path Of Image in CoreData in the Attribute userImage(NSString).the path is saved successfully.now i need to display image in UIImageView by retrieving the saved path.but i am getting empty ImageView.i am doing this.how to do.

```
 UIImage *img = [_usersDataArray    valueForKey:@"userimage"];   
  _userImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:img];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saving the image path you can get the image by:

```
NSString imagePath = imagePathFromMO;// image path from the managed object
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath ];
```

Comment: i did in same way.i am getting imagePath correctly but when i tried to print img(second line of your code) it showing Null.

Comment: and i also i have imageView in my story board.i need to display this image in storyboard.

Comment: Can you post here the imagePath you are using?

Comment: /users/<user Name>/library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Application/<SDK version>/Documents.sun.png   this is my path

Comment: still i am not getting image in my imageview

Comment: Double check your path, it is not correct, it should be ../Documents/sun.png

Comment: where i am doing mistake

Comment: I ma a little confused here, if you print `imagePath` what do you get??

Comment: i am using somulator 7.0

Comment: if i am trying to print imagePath i am getting total path what i posted few minute back.

Comment: ok then you are saving the URL wrong, it should be: /users/<user Name>/library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Application/<SDK version>/Documents/sun.png